# Using Hashmap making plagiarism checker based on Java

Tags: hashmap

it reads input.txt file and compared with target file. 
If more than 3words are same as input file, the program should say plagiarized from .

I used substring so the program only compares first 3 letters.

should use tokenized? or how can it compared

Here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class CheckPlagiarism{


public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    //Init HashMap
    HashMap<String, Integer> corpus = new HashMap<>();
    String fileName = args[0];
    String tragetName = args[1];
    int matchCount = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    Scanner  scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        String[] line = scanner.nextLine().split(":");
        corpus.put(line[1], Integer.parseInt(line[0]));
    }

    boolean found = false;
    scanner  = new Scanner(new File(tragetName));
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        line = line.string(0,matchCount);


        for(Entry<String, Integer> temp: corpus.entrySet()){

            String key=temp.getKey();
            if(key.contains(line))

            {
            System.out.println("Plagiarized from " + temp.getValue());
            found = true;
            break;

            }
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        System.out.println("Not Plagiarized");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: input.txt should contain                                                                              134:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
145:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pellentesque turpis lorem, at convallis massa euismod quis. Cras blandit rutrum lacus tempor suscipit. Vestibulum in sagittis sem. Vestibulum id gravida felis. Morbi venenatis interdum purus a tincidunt. Aenean vel maximus magna.

Comment: target.txt should contain The quick brown fox ate its breakfast slowly